# Sliding a fragment over another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I want to be able to slide a fragment over another one like in Shazam app :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmGwx.png - starting state

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vdGM.png - sliding

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgmDL.png

How is that (or can be) implemented?

Comment: You can use BottomSheets from the support library: http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say layout1 is the layout in the background and layout2 is the layout that can slides over layout1.

You could create a ScrollView where the first element has the same height of layout1 and full width. Make that element transparent so that layout1 is visible and clickable and put layout2 below it.

Now you put layout1 and the ScrollView in a FrameLayout. If ScrollView has enough content you will be able to scroll it.

It would give something like :

```
<FrameLayout>
  <Layout1/>
  <ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout> 
      <View/> // Same height as Layout 1 and width is match_parent
      <Layout2/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What would be more efficient, your method, or the one the Francesc suggested with BottomSheets?
Thanks

Comment: It depends on the complexity of what you want to achieve. If you only need to have a layout slides over another I would go for what I suggested. Using the BottomSheet seems overkill for that case as you would have to set it to actually only scroll.

If you plan to build something more complex. With animations and stuff ... The BottomSheets and CoordinatorLayout is more suited as you can make your own behavior and listen to the scroll events.

Comment: well I need to have a grid list of items in the sliding fragment. Each view in that grid would have its own image, and a couple of texts.. 
HOWEVER, the grid list would be in the form of rows of horizontal-scrollable grid lists.  That means the sliding fragment would have a few grid lists that would be horizontally scrollable.
Does that count for something ''complex" ? What would you choose in this case?
Thank you

Comment: By complex I mean the communication between the sliding fragment and anything else(such as having animations depending on the scroll of the sliding fragment) not the complexity of the fragment in itself.

For what you want to achieve I would go for what I suggested.